# Java android event bus open camera

Tags: java, android

On android 7.0 when I want to open a camera in logs I see this :

```
EventBus: Could not dispatch event: class pl.eltegps.smokkomunikator.event.PhotoRequestedEvent to subscribing class class pl.eltegps.smokkomunikator.ui.activity.MainActivity
                                                                    android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/pl.eltegps.smokkomunikator/images/gps_TEMP.jpg exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()
                                                                        at android.os.StrictMode.onFileUriExposed(StrictMode.java:1799)
                                                                        at android.net.Uri.checkFileUriExposed(Uri.java:2346)
                                                                        at android.content.ClipData.prepareToLeaveProcess(ClipData.java:832)
                                                                        at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:9483)
                                                                        at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:9468)
                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1525)
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4399)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:48)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:75)
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4358)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:871)
                                                                        at pl.eltegps.smokkomunikator.ui.activity.MainActivity.onPhotoRequestedEvent(MainActivity.java:399)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus.invokeSubscriber(EventBus.java:485)
                                                                        at org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus.postToSubscription(EventBus.java:416)
                                                                        at org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus.postSingleEventForEventType(EventBus.java:397)
                                                                        at org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus.postSingleEvent(EventBus.java:370)
                                                                        at org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:251)
                                                                        at pl.eltegps.smokkomunikator.ui.fragment.NewMessageFragment.photo(NewMessageFragment.java:259)
                                                                        at pl.eltegps.smokkomunikator.ui.fragment.NewMessageFragment$$ViewBinder$1.doClick(NewMessageFragment$$ViewBinder.java:28)
                                                                        at butterknife.internal.DebouncingOnClickListener.onClick(DebouncingOnClickListener.java:22)
                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6199)
                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23647)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

On android 4.4.2 I check and it works corretly, but on new android it doesn't works corretly and I don't know why ...

Comment: Can you paste the code you are using to access the camera?

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem I faced also faced while testing on 7.0 . Seems like you can not use getUri() Directly on 7.0 without the use of content provider.

```
takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                            FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(), getActivity().getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", f));
```

You will have to use this and add a provider.xml in xml directory of your project.

[this](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-share-access-to-file-with-fileprovider-on-android-nougat/en) link has detailed explaination about it.